# Непроизвольное очищение сессии

Tags: php, сессия

После кода ниже сессия становиться девственно чиста. По крайней мере ее поле name. Почему, помогите, прошу вас!

```
<?
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
define('_lock_', '');
include('../utils/magic.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) header('Location: http://fludilnya.org/');
include('../bin/db.php');
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Салун математиков "Флудильня"</title> 
<link href="http://nikitalapkov.ru/inc/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://nikitalapkov.ru/inc/bootstrap/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="http://nikitalapkov.ru/inc/bootstrap/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="http://nikitalapkov.ru/inc/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://nikitalapkov.ru/inc/bootstrap/css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link href="http://nikitalapkov.ru/inc/bootstrap/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?include('../layouts/header.php')?>
<?
if(isset($_GET['lesson']))$query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `lessons` WHERE `id`="'.$id.'"'); else $query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `problems` WHERE `id`="'.$id.'"');
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0) die('<div class="alert alert-danger">Не найдено в базе! :(</div>'); else $p=mysql_fetch_array($query);
print_r($p);
if($p['from']!=$_SESSION['id']) echo ('<h2 class="text-center">Хакер?</h2><img src="../img/haker.png">');

if(isset($_GET['lesson']))mysql_query('DELETE FROM `lessons` WHERE `id`='.$id); else mysql_query('DELETE FROM `problems` WHERE `id`='.$id);

$_SESSION['deleted']=1;
print_r($_SESSION);
//header('Location: http://fludilnya.org/');
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?print_r($_SESSION)?>
```

Comment: откуда такая уверенность, что именно в этом «коде» пропадает значение сессии?

Comment: что за файл magic.php ??

Comment: @Gedweb, потому что все это происходит после его исполнения.

Comment: @mountpoint, http://csrf.htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @Arc, а вы знаете, так, между прочим, что в вашем коде после отправки `header` пользователь перейдет на указанные адрес, но код, который идет после `header` будет продолжать работать?

Comment: да, безусловно, но как это связанно?